# Random function in Python won't work

Tags: python, random

I'm trying to generate random sentences but it does not work, I already imported random and this is what I have:

```
    if "razor blade" in inventory:
        sentences = ("What do you take yourself for?","Are you insane?", "You are not doing that.", "You have to be joking.", "This isn't going to work.")
        num= random.randrange (0,5)
        print (sentences[num])
    elif "razor blade" not in inventory:
        print ("you don't own this item in your inventory.")
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you can use `else:` instead of `elif` in this case, your current code should work though

Comment: I don't get an error message, it just repeats "What do you take yourself for?" every time

Comment: It sounds like you might be repeatedly re-seeding `random` to the same seed elsewhere in your program.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `random.choice`:

```
import random
if "razor blade" in inventory:
    sentences = ("What do you take yourself for?","Are you insane?", "You are not doing that.", "You have to be joking.", "This isn't going to work.")
    print(random.choice(sentences))
elif "razor blade" not in inventory:
    print ("you don't own this item in your inventory.")
```

Comment: ah it didn't work :( it's just doing the same thing and repeating "What do you take yourself for?"

Comment: @John it works fine for me when I run it. Try again.

Comment: it still won't work. The code before it is:
 elif decision== "use razor on comb" or "use razor on bottle" or "use razor on sink" or "use razor on toilet" or "use razor on jail bars" or "use razor on locking mechanism":

Comment: maybe the "or" function creates the glitch?

Comment: @John that code in and of itself is incorrect. You need: `elif decision == "use razor on comb" or decision == "use razor on bottle" or decision == ...` etc.

Comment: @John what you have now in your elif statement is one comparison, `elif decision == "use razor on comb"` and then rest `"use razor on jail bars" or "use razor on locking mechanism"` is checking for truthy values since there is no comparison with another value. Non-empty strings are considered true, and since you are using at least `or`, the control comparison will evaluate to true and the statement will always execute.

Comment: ah, it still couldn't function the way I wanted to. Thank you for the explanation and help, though! I think I'll just go for the longer version of executing this .

Comment: @John Ok, let me now if you need any help.

Comment: This code is correct, and Python's random functions work just fine. If your code still isn't working, then there's code your not showing us that is the problem.